# MySQL: Simple subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm new to a bit more advanced MySQL and would like to learn how to do things properly with queries like the following.

I have two tables: sensors and measurement_data
Each sensor row has an id and each measurement_data row links to one of those sensor ids.

What I need to do is get sensors
(SELECT id FROM sensors)
and then get last 5 measurement_data rows for each sensor
(SELECT val FROM measurement_data WHERE sensor_id = *sensor id* ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5)

The result should look something like following json:

```
{
     "SENSOR01": [
         "10","11","12","13","14"
     ],
     "SENSOR02": [
         "10","11","12","13","14"
     ]
}
```

I tried to look at some examples google found for me, but they all were either too complex or at least I didn't get them.
I also tried to play with subqueries based on documentation, but did not understand how to do this.
Could someone help me get on right tracks with this?

Cheers

Comment: That's not a simple subquery, but it's the max-n-per-id problem

Comment: Have a look at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all values using following query, but not sure how to limit them to 5

SELECT sensors.*, GROUP_CONCAT(measurement.id SEPARATOR ',' ) FROM sensors, measurement_data WHERE sensors.sensor_id = measurement.sensor_id group by sensor_id